# Passed parameters to the component __constructor not rendering in blade file

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed recent version of Laravel and PHP. I am getting no errors but when passing the parameters to the component with controller it's not rendering in view `page.bla`.

Controller file - Input.php

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Input extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $name;
    public $type;
    public $label;

    public function __construct($type,$name,$label)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render(){
        return view('components.input');
        }
}
```

View Blade file - input.blade.php

```
<div>
    <!-- Smile, breathe, and go slowly. - Thich Nhat Hanh -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">{{$label}}</label>
        <input type="{{$type}}" id = "" class="form-control" name="{{$name}}">
         <span class = "text-danger">
            {{--
              @error('name')
                  {{$message}}
              @enderror
            --}}
         </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

---

Home page for - home.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1 class = "text-center">Register</h1>
        <form action="{{url('/')}}/register" method = "post">
            @csrf
            <div class="container">
                <x-input type = "text" name = "name" label = "Name"/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[This is the result of about code its input tag is not rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cnFR.png)

I tried passing the data without controller. It worked certainly for some variable names not for different all variable names.

---

Component calling:

```
<x-header users="John"/>
```

---

Component file:

```
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Header extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $users;
    public function __construct($users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */


    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.header');
    }
}
```

---

View:

```
<div>
    <!-- Breathing in, I calm body and mind. Breathing out, I smile. - Thich Nhat Hanh -->
    <h2 class = "text-center">Hi This is Header Page</h2>
    <p class = "text-center">{{$users}}</p>

</div>
```

This worked for only this user's variable. What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling it using livewire magic tag?

Just like mention in livewire documentation here.
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components

```
<livewire:input :type="text" :name="name" :label="{{ __('Label name') }}" />
```

This will receive your parameters and render the view properly.

And than use mount inside your Input component

```
class Input extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $type;
    public $label;

    public function mount(string $type, string $name, string $label)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.input');
    }
}
```

Comment: No It did not change anything.Its giving same output

Comment: did you have any error in laravel.log ?

Comment: as pointed out here https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components , I suggest you use `mount()` instead of `__construct()`

Comment: it remains unchanged.     <livewire:input :type="text" :name="name" :label="{{ __('Enter your name') }}" /> on inspection its showing the same code not rendered

Comment: you only have one root element <div> inside input.blade , right ? if still not working, try to name this component to anything but input, for example DynamicInput